# How spring webflux manages threads while performing async IO

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
Mono<Void> sendRequestAsync(Data data, Info info,
    Map<String, Order> orderMapEntry, String provider) {
  return fromCallable(() -> sendRequest(data, info, orderMapEntry, provider))
      .flatMap(result -> handleResponse(result, orderMapEntry, info))
      .retryWhen(requestRetrySpec)
      .subscribeOn(elasticScheduler);
}
```

I have above code to request (IO) some data from an external entity. I'm using boundedElastic Scheduler for running the pipeline async and not block the flow on subscribe.

My question is, what happens to the thread waiting for the response from the server.

1. The thread sleeps and CPU switches to some other thread?
2. The thread starts doing some other task and onNext event from publisher a new thread starts processing the response from server?